# $x^x=x$: How can I prove that the root $x=-1$ exists?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation itself is pretty simple. We know that the exponential function $y=a^x$ is defined only for $a>0$ and $a≠1$.

In our case, I thought to do this:

$$x^x=x \implies x^x=x^1 \implies x=1$$
or
$$x \cdot \ln{x}=\ln{x} \implies \ln{x} \cdot (x-1)=0 \implies x=1$$
where $x>0$.

You can clearly see that in both cases we get the answer $x=1$ without much difficulty, but $x=-1$ is also the correct answer, what is the analytical way to get it?

Most likely, this is due to features $1$:
$$1=1^1=1^{-1};$$
$$-1=-1^1=-1^{-1}.$$
It turns out that when raising $1$ to the power $±1$, the result does not change, unlike all other values (except $0$). $1$ and $0$ are numbers with special properties and the rules for them are different.

Comment: The equation $f(x) = 0$ has a root $r \iff f(r) = 0.$  If $f(x) = x^x$, then what is $f(-1)$.

Comment: It is not quite right that the exponential function $y=a^x$ is only defined for $a>0$ and $a\neq1$. First, the definition
$$
a^x=\exp(x\log a)
$$
makes sense even if $a=1$ (it's just that the function $1^x$ is not one-to-one). The second issue is that there are cases where $a^x$ makes sense even if $a<0$. As you yourself have mentioned,
$$
(-1)^{-1}=\frac{1}{-1}=-1 \, .
$$
In general, if $a<0$, then the function $a^x$ is defined whenever $x$ is a rational number with an odd denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to $|x|^x=|x|$.
This is possible only if $~~|x|=0,1~~$ or $~~x=1~~$.
Checking for $x=-1,0,1$ we see that $x=1,-1$ are solutions

Comment: I see, in this case we can also take the natural logarithm of both sides $x\ln{|x|}=\ln{|x|} \implies \ln{|x|}(x-1)=0$; here we assume that $|x|≠0$ from  $\ln{|x|}$, and we get $x=±1$